# How to do 2X3 subfloats for a figure?

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I have 6 figures of the same size and I would like them to be subfiqures in a figure in the format so that they are all aligned with 3 figures on the first row and 3 figures directly below.

I have tried the following which gives me 3 figures in each row but are all misaligned (I use the subfig package but it causes a problem as I have the subcaption pacakage too):

```
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \begin{figure}
    \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cXX@{}}

    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image1}} 
    & \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image2}} & \subfloat[C]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image3}} \
    \newline
    & \subfloat[D]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image4}}   \subfloat[E]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image5}} 
    & \subfloat[F]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image6}}\    \end{tabular}

    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Many figures}\label{figure}
    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I complete my code snippet to MWE and add image of figures.

I'm pretty sure, that your question is duplicate ... anyway, try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\hfil
\subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\hfil 
\subfloat[C]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}} 

\subfloat[D]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\hfil   
\subfloat[E]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\hfil
\subfloat[F]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\caption{Many figures}\label{figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

As you can see, the use of `tabularx` and `tabular` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this, which does not need subfig, nor subcaption. It gives you a little bit more control IMO.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width=62mm]{image1_1row.png}%
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width=62mm]{image2_1row.png}%
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width=62mm]{image3_1row.png}
\\[-0.7cm]
\begin{tabular}{m{13mm} m{49mm} m{49mm} m{1mm}}
& (a) & (b) & (c)
\end{tabular}
\\[-0.5cm]
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width=62mm]{image4_2row.png}%
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width=62mm]{image5_2row.png}%
\hspace*{-1cm}
\includegraphics[width=62mm]{image6_3row.png}
\\[-0.7cm]
\begin{tabular}{m{13mm} m{49mm} m{49mm} m{1mm}}
& (d) & (e) & (f)
\end{tabular}
\caption[Short caption for table of figures]{Longer caption explaining each image from (a) to (f).}
\label{Fig:6_images}
\end{figure}
```