# how to insert multi figures with multi captions in latex

Tags: graphics

[image]

Similar to above image in latex article,how to insert multi single images,
every image have caption on top and below of a image,and between two columns, draw a line like above color image, and the number of images together have a caption.Please help me

Comment: my gmail is :xyzgfu@gmail.com

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour and read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. Have a look to ... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360828/how-to-do-2x3-subfloats-for-a-figure/360830#360830  (maybe it will help you)

Comment: You can use `\caption` for the overall caption, package `subcaption` for the *(a)*, *(b)*, *(c)*, *(d)* captions and simple text for the captions above the single images. Additionally you could use four `tabulars` for the four parts *(a)*, *(b)*, *(c)*, *(d)*.

Comment: hi,Schweinebacke,if I use tabulars environment,the distance between of two colunm(in other words,two subfigures) is big,so how to control the distance between two subfigures in a row?Similar to my above image,how to adjust the distance between two subfigures?I feel that this distance is big,so I want to reduce this distance.

Comment: Have a look at my question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361579/subcaption-calculating-the-width. It provides the code (in general) you ask for in my opinion.